# Why doesn't if else shorthand work with break - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have been trying break out of loop when a condition is matched. I've tried one-liners below:

```
break if a is not None else time.sleep(1)
```

and this

```
a is not None and break
time.sleep(1)
```

Both are not working & throwing `SyntaxError` while the straight forward works fine.

```
if a is not None:
    break
time.sleep(1)
```

While I've no problem with using it this way, I just want to know why the syntax for above is wrong.

Comment: It's just because of the way the syntax is defined. `break` is a statement on its own, but not an expression, so it can't be combined with anything else in a single statement.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that syntax should work. Can you give an example of a similar case where that works?

Comment: You also can't do things like `f(break)` or `x = break` for the same reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression  *expression* `if` *expression* `else` *expression* is a ternary operator. The expressions are evaluated. `break` is a statement. It isn't evaluated, it's executed. You're getting a syntax error because the syntax is not correct.

As @hugo Rivera says below, "All expressions are statements, but not all statements are expressions."

Answer (score 3):

*All expressions are statements, but not all statements are expressions.*

The ternary operator [`X if B else Y`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) only accepts expressions `X`, `B` and `Y`, but [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-break_stmt) is a statement and cannot be used as an expression.

Similarly, you can't `return`, `import`, assign, etc... in a ternary operator. See the second link for a full list of statements.